# Formtastic select list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formtastic

```
<% semantic_form_for(@product, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>

    <% f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.input :name %>
        <%= f.input :price %>
        <%= f.input :pno %>
        <%= f.input :description %>
        <%= f.input :shop_category %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Product belongs to Shop_category, Shop_category belongs to Shop.

How to change the line :

```
<%= f.input :shop_category %>
```

To show only shop_categories that belongs to Shop with id for example 15 instead of showing all shop_categories in the select box ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a `:collection`  option for the select input.

```
<%= form.input :shop_category, :collection => @shop.ShopCategories %>
```

So you can, by providing a Hash to that collection attribute, display the categories you need, with the required conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you set the shop_category in the controller, it will already be selected as a default value.

Comment: Also you could (and should?) do it in the model: `after_initialize { self.attribute_name ||= defaul_value }`.